# How to use Expressions to check for !=null against user-defined data types?

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees

I'm new to expressions. I'm trying this and it doesn't seem to work.

```
ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Customer));
Expression left = Expression.Property(pe, "OrderList");
Expression right = Expression.Constant(null, typeof(Nullable));
Expression res = Expression.NotEqual(left, right);
```

I'm gettign an "InvalidOperationException". In simple If-Else statement is look like this

```
if(custObj.OrderList != null)
{...}
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Does `OrderList` return an object of type `Nullable`?  I doubt it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are comparing objects of different types.
You can solve this by using `Expression.Constant(object value)` overload, 
I'm assuming that the type of the property `OrderList` is by reference, if not you can't do this comparison.

```
ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Customer));
Expression left = Expression.Property(pe, "OrderList");
Expression right = Expression.Constant(null);
Expression res = Expression.NotEqual(left, right);
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use

```
Expression right = Expression.Constant(null, left.Type);
```

It will give you the `null` constant with the same type as the left operand (property in your case).